# What is the format of the bundle properties for karaf's features-maven-plugin generate-features-xml goal

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf

To list a bunch of bundles you want included in a generated features.xml, the docs say:

```
bundles File     A properties file that contains a list of bundles that will be used to generate the features.xml file
```

But it neglects to say what format this file should be in.  The docs give the example:

```
        <execution>
          <id>generate</id>
          <phase>generate-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>generate-features-xml</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <bundles>src/main/resources/bundles.properties</bundles>
            <outputFile>target/features.xml</outputFile>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
```

Anyone know what this file should look like?

Comment: Have you tried `groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version`? The document said as The example below generates one feature that installs bundle `mvn:org.apache:bundle1:1.0`. I think the format should be same.

Comment: @marathon - any luck finding an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

The correct format is

```
groupId/artifactId/version/type
```

example:

```
org.apache/bundle1/1.0/bundle
```

For what it's worth, I attempted to get the feature plugin to work for me, but it did not, in part because of the poor documentation.  I wanted to build a features.xml dynamically that would replace the version of my bundle and the bundles in my feature.  It was easier to just use maven filtering to achieve my goal, so that's what I did.